# mb_convert_encoding() different results depending on PHP version

Tags: php, windows, encoding, console

In PHP 5.6, I have always used the next function to echo UTF-8 strings in Windows console with no issue:

```
function console($utf8_string) {
    $dos = mb_convert_encoding($utf8_string, "CP850", mb_detect_encoding($utf8_string, "UTF-8, CP850, ISO-8859-15", true));
    echo $dos;
}
```

When I make this call,

```
console('LA PIÑA ESTÁ DELICIOSA');
```

It echoes, as expected,

```
LA PIÑA ESTÁ DELICIOSA
```

The question is that in PHP 7.2 (I have not tested another versions), it echoes

```
LA PIA EST DELICIOSA
```

Comment: If you run it using https://3v4l.org/lJpqS, the output is the same for all versions.  There must be something else affecting the output.

Comment: `mb_convert_encoding()` is pretty much useless, I've never understood why it's so popular. If it's ever worked for you, it was probably by pure chance. My guess is that you hit an edge case precisely when you switched versions, but it probably hadn't worked with the old server.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I have tested in 7.2 and 8.1 (in different computers but Windows environment both of them) and, suprisingly, the echo command shows special characters correctly, whatever the codepage in the console window is active.

Comment: You can use `bin2hex()` to see the actual output. The outcome of just printing totally depends on the encoding (both the encoding of text and the encoding used by whatever tool you use to render, e.g. the browser).